# Actual value is not showing in bullet chart of sapui5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying a splitApp, I have used the BulletChart in the details page, I want to show the BulletChart (Actual value should be taken from the master page selected item).

My Master.Controller:

```js
itemSelected: function () {
    var app = sap.ui.getCore().byId("appid");
    var list = sap.ui.getCore().byId("listid");

    var sitem = list.getSelectedItem();
    var spath = sitem.oBindingContexts.data.sPath;

    var oitem = sap.ui.getCore().getModel('data').getProperty(spath);

    var Model = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oitem);
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(Model, 'item');

    app.toDetail("detailsid", "show");
}
```

My Details Page View:

```js
var oBCTmpl = new sap.suite.ui.commons.BulletChart({
    //id:"bullet",
    size: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileSize.Auto,
    scale: "INR",
    actual: [{
        value: "{item>/Amount}",
        color: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileValueColor.Error
    }],
    targetValue: 2500,
    thresholds: [
        {value: 0,    color: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileValueColor.Good},
        {value: 1000, color: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileValueColor.Good},
        {value: 2000, color: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileValueColor.Good},
        {value: 3000, color: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileValueColor.Good},
        {value: 4000, color: sap.suite.ui.commons.InfoTileValueColor.Error}
    ],
    showActualValue: true,
    showTargetValue: true,
    showDeltaValue: true,
    showValueMarker: false,
    mode: sap.suite.ui.commons.BulletChartMode.Actual
});
```

Output:
[image]

Why is the Actual value not showing in the chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data binding in "*My Details Page View*" seems OK.
Some of your code is missing. So it has to be something with either the list implementation you've chosen and/or binding info/data you use from the selected item.

One of the recomendation is to use the following:

```
sitem.getBindingContext().getPath();
```

instead of:

```
sitem.oBindingContexts.data.sPath;
```

See an example with SplitApp and sap.m.SelectList [in jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vladdy/pLqqxbfs/8/) (click on an arbitrary item on the left).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now the code is selecting the items from the master page but it is still not showing the data in the bullet graph after selecting the items.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something. Each time I click on an item (IE, FF, Chrome), it changes the value of the graph on the right - 500NIR, 600 NIR, 700 NIR. See [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8lq6_OxBX48NTR5OXI2QzItRGs/view?usp=sharing)